# How to make a Custom Facebook Share Button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am trying to make a custom Facebook Share button, by providing my own img and applying FB.ui() to it, but the method opens the dialogue stating:

***Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.***

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**index.php:**

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Why can't I" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="get this thing to work" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/images/whyaretherenoexamplesanywhere.jpg" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
    (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    // more div's

</body>
```

in a div on index.php, the file ajaxPage.php is loaded, by means of an ajax call. this in itself and everything in it works perfectly.

In this file an image exists as a button, bound by a .click() method, which together prompt the dialogue for sharing:

**ajaxPage.php:**

```
// In de DOM:
<img class="customFacebookIcon" src="enoughwiththefunnynames.jpg"/>

// In the <script>:
$('.customFacebookIcon').click(function(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        appId: '12345678901234567890',
        href: 'http://www.example.com',
    }, function(response){});
});
```

Comment: Make sure that you have made changes in your Facebook application settings. You have to set the domain name and website link in facebook app settings.

Comment: Go to your App Settings page and make sure that the domain that you have specified for your App matches the domain that you are implementing this on.